# Show and Navigate the user to a different PanoramaItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone, panorama-control

I am developing a Panorama application. In one of the Panorama item, I have a list of categories. On Selecting one of the list item, I have display all the feeds under that category in a new Panorama Item. So I decided to use a Panorama item say item 4, initially set to collapsed. And then when the user select a category, make that item 4 visible to true and navigate the user to that item 4. and change the title of that item to the category they selected.

1. Is this the right way to do it?
2. If So, how can I navigate the user to another item programmatic?
3. I am facing another issue where even if I change the title, the change is not taking effect unless a new page load? (I also read that MSDN has stated in its guidelines that it is not advisable to change the title of an Panorama item)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal opinion is that the `Panorama` (and `Pivot`) control should not be used to display dynamic items in one item based on a selection in another item. Take a look at this [channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Jaime+Rodriguez/Windows-Phone-Design-Days-Pivot-and-Pano) where Chad Roberts and Amy Alberts discuss these two key controls.

My suggestion would be to navigate to another page on category selection and to load the feeds under that category in the target page. Shawn Wildermuth has a [blog post](http://wildermuth.com/2010/10/11/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_1_of_10_Navigation_Framework) on page navigation if you need any help in that respect.